# Applying macro from worksheet to workbook

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub ScreenTip()
    Dim hl As Hyperlink

    For Each hl In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        hl.ScreenTip = CStr(hl.Range.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

I have this code but it only runs on the Worksheet that you are currently on. I would like it to run over the whole workbook. How would I change this to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your `For Each` and add a new variable

```
Sub ScreenTip()
    Dim hl As Hyperlink
    Dim ws as WorkSheet

    For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each hl In ws.Hyperlinks
            hl.ScreenTip = CStr(hl.Range.Value)
        Next hl
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: It says type mismatch then highlights     hl.ScreenTip = CStr(hl.Range.Value)

Comment: @MichaelDowney I couldn't tell you why, it works just fine for me. Did you try walking through it with the debugger one step at a time? Also to note, I didn't change that line of code throwing the error any, that was from your original post.

Comment: Had another excel file open that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub ScreenTip()
Dim hl As Hyperlink
dim sh as worksheet
dim bk as workbook
set bk = whateverbook
for each sh in bk.sheets
    For Each hl In sh.Hyperlinks
        hl.ScreenTip = CStr(hl.Range.Value)
    Next hl
next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: LOL coke's on you!